# How can I automatically set the resolution on uv4l at startup

Tags: uv4l

I have had a webcam setup with port forwarding and dynamic DNS - everything works fine except I would like to automatically set the resolution of the `uv4l server` to 1024x768 when the Raspberry Pi starts up. At the moment, this has to be done manually for the webcam size to work correctly.

I am inclined to think I could do this with a script that gets run after `@reboot`. I'm a bit rusty on my syntax, but here's what I've tried (without luck):

I have a script called `start-uv4l.sh` which gets executed after reboot.

```
#!/bin/sh
uv4l --auto-video_nr --driver raspicam --encoding mjpeg 
--server-option '--enable-webrtc-audio=0' 
-—server-option '--janus-video-format=50'
```

I have given the file execute permissions, so all should work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated otherwise I will have to consider physically re-positioning the webcam.